# Delete local printer

Tags: vb.net, printing

I've got a desktop application with a listview filled with installed printers on my local computer. This is a simple printer managed, so I want to be able to right click on an item and then delete that particular printer. How can I do this?

Here is how I list the printers

```
Public Sub listInstalledPrinters()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim pkInstalledPrinters As String

        For i = 0 To printersettings.InstalledPrinters.Count - 1
            pkInstalledPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Item(i)
            listViewLocal.Items.Add(pkInstalledPrinters, nIndex)
        Next

    End Sub
```

But how can I delete one of them? Is there a built-in way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you query the printers via [`System.Management.ManagementScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.aspx), you can easily delete them using the [`Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2k71172.aspx) method of the [`ManagementObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wfhy6hw.aspx) class.

```
Dim scope = New ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath)
scope.Connect()
Dim printers = New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Printer")).[Get]()
For Each printer As ManagementObject In printers
    Dim nameOfPrinter = printer("Name").ToString()

     If nameOfPrinter = "ThePrinterYouWantToDelete" Then
         printer.Delete()
     End If
Next
```

Comment: Almost working! Except for the error message 'delete' is not a member of 'System.Management.ManagementBaseObject'. Something wrong with the ManagementObjectSearcher?

Comment: See my edit. Try `For Each printer As ManagementObject In` instead of `For Each printer In`